# Segue to a view controller when app opens from a NSLocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I need a way to segue way to a view controller when the app opens from a `NSLocalNotification`.

I don't really know where to start and I can't find any examples on how to do it online. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start:

Do you know how to initiate a segue through code? If not, see the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs and search around here for `prepareForSegue` and `performSegueWithIdentifier` There are lots of hits. Also this is a good tutorial: [iOS 5 Storyboard: How To use Segues, Scenes and Static Content UITableViews](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219) but there are many out there.

Have you worked with [UILocalNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? See the [UILocalNotification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1) for an overview.

In terms of handling the event, that is done by the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate) See the event method: `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

> Local notifications are similar to remote push notifications, but
> differ in that they are scheduled, displayed, and received entirely on
> the same device. An application can create and schedule a local
> notification, and the operating system then delivers it at the
> schedule date and time. If it delivers it when the application is not
> active in the foreground, it displays an alert, badges the application
> icon, or plays a sound—whatever is specified in the
> UILocalNotification object. If the application is running in the
> foreground, there is no alert, badging, or sound; instead, the
> application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method is called if the
> delegate implements it.

How you handle a UILocalNotification will depend on the state of your app: foreground, background, inactive.